# bootstrap blocks asp.net textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this template
http://www.egrappler.com/templatevamp-free-twitter-bootstrap-admin-template/

It's free and using twitter bootstrap. Bootstrap blocking asp.net elements. First I couldn't click the buttons then I solved it with adding UseSubmitBehavior="False" tag to button.

But now I cant insert any record to mssql database. Textboxes just returns null value.

I read a lots of solution but no-one works.

My Html

```
<div class="main-inner">

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="span12">            

            <div class="widget ">

                <div class="widget-header">
                    <i class="icon-user"></i>
                    <h3>Cari Ekle</h3>
                </div> <!-- /widget-header -->

                <div class="widget-content">
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_carikodu" placeholder="Cari Kodu" runat="server" Width="20%"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txt_cariadi" placeholder="Cari Adı" runat="server" Width="50%"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txt_cariyetkili" placeholder="Yetkili" runat="server" Width="25%"></asp:TextBox>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_adres1" placeholder="Adres" runat="server" Width="99%"></asp:TextBox>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_sabittel1" placeholder="Sabit Tel 1" runat="server" Width="18%"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txt_sabittel2" placeholder="Sabit Tel 2" runat="server" Width="18%"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txt_faks" placeholder="Faks" runat="server" Width="18%"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txt_ceptel1" placeholder="Cep Tel 1" runat="server" Width="18%"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txt_ceptel2" placeholder="Cep Tel 2" runat="server" Width="18%"></asp:TextBox>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_il" placeholder="İl" runat="server" Width="32%"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txt_ilce" placeholder="İlçe" runat="server" Width="32%"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txt_ulke" placeholder="Ülke" runat="server" Width="32%"></asp:TextBox>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_vd" placeholder="Vergi Dairesi" runat="server" Width="32%"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txt_vn" placeholder="Vergi No" runat="server" Width="32%"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;<br />

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_eposta" placeholder="E-posta" runat="server" Width="32%"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txt_web" placeholder="Web" runat="server" Width="32%"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;<br />

                    <asp:Button ID="btn_ekle" runat="server" Text="Kaydet" class="btn btn-default" UseSubmitBehavior="False" OnClick="btn_ekle_Click" />

                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" Text="Button" />

                    </asp:Panel>

                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Visible="false">
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" type="button">
                                ×
                            </button>
                            <strong>Cari Eklendi!</strong> Cari bilgileri kaydedildi.
                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>


                </div> <!-- /widget-content -->

            </div> <!-- /widget -->

        </div> <!-- /span8 -->




      </div> <!-- /row -->

    </div> <!-- /container -->

</div> <!-- /main-inner -->
```

And C#

```
  SqlConnection baglanti1 = new     SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bag2"].ConnectionString);
        string ins = "Insert into cariler (carikodu,cariadi,cariyetkili,cariadres1,sabittel1,sabittel2,faks,ceptel1,ceptel2,il,ilce,ulke,eposta,web,vergidairesi,vergino) Values (@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4,@p5,@p6,@p7,@p8,@p9,@p10,@p11,@p12,@p13,@p14,@p15,@p16)";
        SqlCommand komut1 = new SqlCommand(ins, baglanti1);

        komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txt_carikodu.Text);
        komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txt_cariadi.Text);
        komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", txt_cariyetkili.Text);
        komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", txt_adres1.Text);
        komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", txt_sabittel1.Text);
        komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", txt_sabittel2.Text);
        komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", txt_faks.Text);
        komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", txt_ceptel1.Text);
        komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", txt_ceptel2.Text);
        komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", txt_il.Text);
        komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p11", txt_ilce.Text);
        komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p12", txt_ulke.Text);
        komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p13", txt_eposta.Text);
        komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p14", txt_web.Text);
        komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p15", txt_vd.Text);
        komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p16", txt_vn.Text);


        baglanti1.Open();
        komut1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        baglanti1.Close();

        Panel1.Visible = false;
        Panel2.Visible = true;
```

Comment: this is why I hate asp and razor markup, It is always easier to write plain html because it can be useded everywhere so you can find solutions everywhere

Comment: Do you have a `<form runat="server">` around what you posted here?

Comment: And this all worked prior to adding that bootstrap template, and the **only** change has been to add the template?

Comment: @DaveParsons query already working. It's adding empty row to my database. Just can't get textbox values.

Comment: @İsmailHakkıŞen: If you remove the template does everything work as expected. I'm curious as to whether it is in fact the template causing an issue or if there is an issue within your code.

Comment: @DaveParsons I don't understand what you exactly say but If soy say to me try your code without bootstrap, I tried and its inserted to row perfectly. here http://i.imgur.com/R53TMPK.png